# Is there any way to store full size image returned from camera activity in internal memory?

Tags: android, camera, android-intent

I am using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(externalFileObj));
```

intent to call default camera activity. To get full image you need to specify intent.putExtra(). But this always requires URI that works only for external storage files.

I tried to create a temp.jpg image in internal memory and pass its URI

```
Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir() + "/temp.jpg"));
```

but the camera activity won't return back after the image is captured.

**So there is no way to get Full size image from default camera application in our activity without using any external storage ?** Assuming that the device do not have SD card or currently in use is there no way I can avoid using it ?

Yes I know we can create our own camerapreview surface but I want to use the default camera application as it is natural with many more options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I got it. Your files directory in internal memory is private by default and is not writable by external apps (e.g. Camera app is external app)

Just create a new directory in writable mode in your application space (internal memory) and pass this URI to the camera Activity. And everything works fine. No need of external storage to be present at all. Tested and works fine.

Comment: Just to add, you will still not be happy with this unless you have root permissions. Because the result image returned by Camera activity in internal memory folder have different permissions group (-rwxrwx---) and your app is not allowed to access it although it is in your application space and your own created folder!

Comment: Can you tell, how can one get root permissions and how can i create a new directory in writeable mode? i am having same issue...

Comment: Root permission are sort of user hacking his mobile for extra privileges. As a developer I advice not to assume such cases, if you intend to publish app in android market and do not want to only target limited audience who have rooted droids. Also this is quite older post not sure over if newer APIs provide any way out.

Comment: Also what it means in above answer is to change permission using adb shell terminal by going in data/data/your app/your folder/ and using chmod unix command.

Answer (score 0):

I have just used code like the following:

```
mTempFilePath = File.createTempFile("myappprefix_", "");
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mTempFilePath));
```

Is there some reason it has to be in internal storage?  I'd expect that only phones like the HTC Incredible (which has internal photo storage) would be able to explicitly store photos on internal.

Comment: Reason for internal storage is that the images taken from camera are confidential and to be used/displayed only for my application. Using external storage gives no way that images are not accessible/modified by other apps or user. I did not find any area other than internal memory for this. If anyone knows a way please let me know.

Comment: Seems like your only bet would be to have the photo taken on external storage and then move it yourself into whatever secure solution you are using to secure the other data in your application.  Note that there are some phones that will automatically add a picture taken with the camera activity into the phone gallery, even if you didn't ask it to do so.  I'm trying to remember exactly which phones I saw that on - perhaps the Droid Eris and a couple other SenseUI phones?

Comment: Thanks for that information. So using camera activity is not wiser, as still it may keep a copy of it. Currently it is enough for me that my copy do not gets modified. So doing the same thing of creating a temp copy on external storage and then moving it back to internal memory. But for other cases of confidentiality it means we cannot rely on default apps. Let me know if you remember the phones which does that.

Comment: In thinking about it, I'm confident that the Droid Eris was one of the phones that always made a copy of the picture.  I believe we saw it on the HTC Hero (Sprint) as well, but I'm afraid I don't have access to the testing notes for that application, as that was with a previous company.  I would say that your analysis is right - if you're concerned about your data integrity, it's fine to have the picture taken on external storage and then move your copy somewhere your app can control it (knowing that on some rare phones, there will be an extra copy).  For confidential info, that's not enough.

Comment: I have posted answer for the problem.

Comment: Your method doesn't work on my Nexus 4.Camera Activity just never return when I confirm the foto.

Comment: @Ivelius when you say it never returns, do you mean your onActivityResult is never called?

Comment: When I say it never returns , I mean that I press OK button on camera activity and it doesn't go away.This happens when I create a file on local storage and pass it as MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT extra.But everything works fine when I create file on external storage.

Comment: @Ivelius strange.  This is on 4.4?  I'm not working on the app where I deal with photos like this any more, but it wouldn't surprise me much if this is a 4.4 specific issue.  They certainly changed how getting pictures from the gallery works, since you can more easily get back photos from other apps where the photo isn't stored locally.

Comment: Unfortunately in this specific case it happens on both 4.4 and 4.2 devices I have. But nevertheless , 4.4 have it's issues regarding image capturing via intent . onActivityResult it returns null in data object.