# How to get FileInputStream for internal memory files in Android ? The file is in my custom folder made in application space

Tags: android, file, memory, internal

How to get FileInputStream for file in internal memory in android which is not inside applications default file directory.

I have created new directory in my application space. So `openFileInput("filename")` will only work for files in `getFilesDir()`. And `openFileInput("filename")` do not accept argument with path separaters "/" so I can change it to ../myfolder/.

Is there any way to get a `FileInputStream` on this ? ..

Note: Using normal APIs File = new File(... ) gives permission denied errors. And I have already created given Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE as the permission for my custom folder.

To make it clear :
My file is here ==> `/data/data/com.app.package/app_myfolder/file1.tmp`
where
"myfolder" ==> is created with `Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` permissions.

I want to open `FileInputStream` on `file1.tmp`. (Normally your files are here `/data/data/com.app.package/files/file1.tmp` and `getFilesDir()` points to this directory, so also `openFileInput("")` takes argument which exist in same default directory.)

Comment: Oh! Actually the problem seems to be the file permission. It gives -rwxrwx--- . So myapp won't have any access to read that file. As the file was created by camera activity as a result for startActivityForResult() for MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent. So is there any way I can change this permissions ? As camera app and myapp are in different groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get FileInputStream for file in internal memory in android which is not inside applications default file directory.

You can't, unless the file in question is created using `openFileOutput()` with `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`, and that's not a very good idea (since any app can now read that file).

> As the file was created by camera activity as a result for startActivityForResult() for MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent.

The camera activity should be storing the file out on external storage, not internal storage. Use the EXTRA_OUTPUT extra to indicate where the file should go.

> So is there any way I can change this permissions ?

Assuming "camera activity" is referring to the one in the Android firmware, you will need to modify the firmware.

Comment: Thanks. But my efforts in doing all this was to avoid external storage, in case when there is no SD card present or currently in use. Here is link for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632231/is-there-any-way-to-store-full-size-image-returned-from-camera-activity-in-intern Anyway it seems that when you call another activity for results, you are dependent on how it gives results back, in this case it handed over me the image with no permissions to access it.(This is the case only for internal memory, for external storage path in EXTRA_OUTPUT you have all access to it)

Comment: @SimpleGuy: You are welcome to write your own camera app. The basics are not particularly hard. Then, you get the data as a byte array and can save it wherever you like. However, if you are going to invoke an external application, you and the application will need to use data stores that are mutually accessible, and raw paths to internal storage will not qualify.

Comment: For anyone that gets here, even if a device has no apparent SD card present, it will still have an external storage directory.