# how to accees Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() when user connected to system

Tags: android

I am working on email application. My application will create some files in the Sd card.

I am using

```
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

to store the files in SD card. But I have observed that some times when my device connected to my computer I am unable to access my files.

Please suggest what's the path I need to use so that my files must always accessible.

I want to store my files only in Sd card.

Comment: use internal memory, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655003/how-to-get-fileinputstream-for-internal-memory-files-in-android-the-file-is-in/4737771#4737771

Answer (score 0):

I think when the SD card is mounted you cannot access it.