# Android:small size image taken by camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdk-2.1

I have called an intent by passing action **"android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"**

i.e. intent.setAction("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");and the image I get is small size.and i want to get Full Sized image of 730X1115 size.How can I get that.

Comment: Here is already some answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632231/is-there-any-way-to-store-full-size-image-returned-from-camera-activity-in-intern

Comment: try to convert your picture into bitmap and specify bitmap size, it may work try it

Comment: but when passed the uri to onactivityResult() then it is giving  NULL in URi????

Comment: still you are getting null in URI? already you solved that one using contentresolver it seems

Comment: no its working but i have a big doubt

Comment: doubt is that as I have overlay two images and given the size then when i draw bitmap on canvas then it should stretch itself to the defined size?why is it so?

Comment: by resizing its working... thanks titus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have scaled that image by giving the dimensions of the border in which it gets fit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

`Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);`

Though both your code and this redirects you to the Native Camera there is been much difference with the quality considerations. May be you should give it a try.

Comment: I have tried it but there is no rectangle coming for cropping image

Comment: But you cannot expect users to drop the images right! It is we who have to do it in program. Once you are done capturing image using camera use bitmap and compress or scale your image accordingly. I believe this is how we do it.

Comment: no no I mean that when we capture the image by camera then i have used crop = true then why is it not showing any rectangle

Comment: and i have already done all this.using bitmap and completed all